# Play SWF on android 4.2 webview

Tags: android, flash

I am building an App with api level 11. this is my Java Code

```
   myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webSitioPublico);

    final ProgressBar Pbar;
    Pbar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progresoSitioPublico);


    WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();                           
    webSettings.setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
    webSettings.setPluginsEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

    setExplorer(url);
```

My SWF is on my own external server

with just

```
  <object width="215" height="140">
  <param name="movie" value="http://192.168.0.198:5771/es/games/paint.swf">
    <embed src="http://192.168.0.198:5771/es/games/paint.swf"
           width="215" height="140">
    </embed>
</object>
```

I am testing on a Nexus 7 4.2.2 api level 17, but building this app for api level 11.

Nothing appears on screen just a box with question marks on the place where SWF should be.

my manifest

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name="Rafael"
    android:hardwareAccelerated = "true">

    <activity
        android:name="Principal"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
         android:theme="@style/AppTheme" 
         android:screenOrientation="portrait"
         android:hardwareAccelerated = "true"
         >

    </activity>





      <service android:name="ScannerService" ></service>
</application>
```

Answer (score 2):

But you can still download apk from adobe
http://helpx.adobe.com/fr/flash-player/kb/archived-flash-player-versions.html

it will work in firefox mobile, the default browser (but not chrome mobile)
i have done it and it work on my galaxy nexus with android 4.2.2 :)

Comment: Thank you, useful for me. It work perfectly on my Galaxy Note 2. Delete Flash player on GG play is a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it isen't possible anymore. 
SWF require Adobe flash who has been deleted from Android

[Adobe Removing Flash for Android From Google Play](http://www.pcmag.com/article2/0,2817,2408526,00.asp)

Answer (score 0):

use it  `myWebView.load(url)` instead of `setExplorer(url);`